# Is it possible to send changeMessage notification at wallet creation?

Tags: ios, symfony, apple-push-notifications, wallet

I have a website with Symfony for create IOS wallet and i want to know if is it possible to send a changeMessage notification to my users when they install wallet on their phones like : Welcome on your wallet !

Is it possible ?

For informations, my changeMessage notification work when i update my user wallet, i create notification parameter to send a notification message with 255 characters Max and my changeMessage call this parameter when pass is update.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but it takes a bit of work.

When a user first installs your pass, iOS will call the web service to register.  Once registered it will immediately make a call to get the latest version of the pass.

If the pass returned is different to the pass originally installed then the change message will trigger.

Since this will happen just once at the time the pass is installed, you should achieve the same experience you describe in your question.